# MongoDB $convert string

Tags: mongodb, charts, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm planning to $convert my field to date because it is currently a string.

My Collection

```
"name": "Roboert Browning",
"delivery": [{
    "status": "Not Started",
    "createdAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z",
    "updatedAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z" 
}, {
    "status": "Accepted",
    "updatedAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z",
    "createdAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z"
}],
"price": 500,
"targetDate": "2020-12-08T11:50:15.659562",
"createdAt": 2020-12-08T11:36:48.285+00:00,
"updatedAt": 2020-12-09T12:02:06.426+00:00
```

I would like to match the *createdAt* to the *targetDate* if they are the same date, but it is currently a string. I want to convert the *targetDate* to **Date** so I can match them.

Current implementation

```
{
    $match: {
        "$expr": { 
            "$eq": [ 
                { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$createdAt" } }, 
                { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$targetDate" } }
            ] 
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error **can't convert from BSON type string to Date**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetDate`, `createdDate` are `string` fields

```
"createdAt": 2020-12-08T11:36:48.285+00:00,
"updatedAt": 2020-12-09T12:02:06.426+00:00
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AWiRZzAGUDZ)

You can do as mentioned in playground i.e using `toDate` if your fields are really date field.

If they are already string, you don't need conversion.